# How to pick the desired contact/contact image when dialing a number shared by two (or more) contacts

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, contacts, phone-app

This is something that's bugged me about Android for a while and I can't figure out how to change it. Basically, it seems like when I add a contact entry to some app, in particular a launcher app that lets you set a button to direct dial a particular contact, if that contact shares the given phone number with another contact, then it just picks one, and in my case it always picks the WRONG one, lol!

An example: Right now I'm trying to set up my mom with her first smartphone, and I put Big Launcher on which will have buttons to call each of us, both cell and home. The problem is that me and my wife both have separate cell phone but share the same home number, of course. So, I add direct dials to both our cell phones and our appropriate images show up. However, when I add a direct dial to MY home phone number, for some reason my wife's image comes up. It is her home number as well, but I would think that especially since it is created via my contact record that it would use my image. The same exact thing is true between my sister and her husband's phones.

Is there any way to get around this? I tried tricking it to see if just formatting the number differently and putting a 1 in front of the area code on one of the contact records would fix it, but it doesn't. It just seems odd that this issue has not been resolved and that there isn't a simple way for apps to let you pick the image/avatar based on the contact record that's chosen...

The phone I'm dealing with right now is a Sprint LG G Flex with Android 4.4.2 Stock, but this is a problem I've noticed on every Android phone I've owned...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the profile photo chosen is based on the contact ID, however an easy (albeit less than ideal) workaround in this situation is to create a unique contact for "Home", set the desired photo there and add that as a separate direct dial option.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the consensus in other forums I've seen this.  Sad that this fairly basic functionality is a big kludge even after 7 years of development of Android. :(